# How to change link styles in BlueMail app?

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, inline

I am creating an email. In the text I've got a long number, like `1234567890`, and it is not a phone number. BlueMail makes a link with attr `href="tel:...` on it. I've tryed different solutions, but it doesn't work in this app. Now I've got:

```html
<a style="Margin: 0; color: #252929; cursor: text; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
  <font style="text-decoration: none; color: #252929;font-weight: bold">12345678</font>
</a>
```

It works everywhere, but not in the BlueMail.

Comment: have you tried a global CSS in the head of the document?

Comment: @Syfer, yes, it doesn't help

Comment: What does the link look like when you receive it? Color gets striped? CSS in head doesnt work?

Comment: @Syfer it is blue and underlined

Comment: @Syfer I've got css in head and in the body, I have no stripes.

Comment: @Syfer thankyou, global style finaly helps, but not not immediately, and only from the middle of the document